# How to get the average of many lists embedded within each other?

Tags: python

This is the simplest case :

```
input [2,3,[4,6]]
```

The program should calculate the average of the list first, and then the average of 2 and 3, afterwards it should calculate the total average:

Comment: About the output: In your explanation you say that the output should be however many lines depending on how many sub-lists there are, how deep they go, etc. But the code you provided only returns one value. Which one is it then? Do you only need the complete average? Do you need separate averages for all the different lists?

Comment: The average of 5 and 2 is 3.75. Why your answer is 3?

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation that supports nested lists, does without any specific library and works with any python version:

```
def nested_avg(elements):
    try:
        seq = iter(elements)
    except TypeError:
        return elements
    s = 0
    while True:
        try:
            el = next(seq)
        except StopIteration:
            return s / len(elements)
        s += nested_avg(el)


l1=[2,3,[4,6]]
print(int(nested_avg(l1)))

l2=[2,3,[4,[5,7]]]
print(int(nested_avg(l2)))
```

Both l1 and l2 inputs produce the same result, i.e. 3

Note: the code does not cover all possible checks on the input data, up to you to make it production-ready :D

Comment: Why have you gone for the `//` operator? I'm worried the result will get wronger and wronger as the sub-lists get deeper. You're effectively rounding all the intermediate answers which means the answer will start to drift off. Am I wrong?